How to debug scroll event fired a lot later than the pointermove event?
With Chrome's 20x slowdown + device emulation, you can see that the first scroll event occurs 230ms after the first pointermove event. There are also multiple pointermove before the first scroll:

On Android (Pixel 8, 2023 phone), without any artificial slowdown, there's also noticeable lag when scrolling. I tried all the common fixes:

GPU acceleration with translateZ(0)
passive: true on scroll handlers
React time slicing
disabling packages one-by-one
avoid layout/paint

Since the web app is too complicated to make an MRE, this question isn't about solving my specific problem. Instead, I'm looking for general ways to debug scroll lag issues. E.g.:

how to tell if a specific CSS property is expensive
how to figure out why "Hit Test" is taking so long
resources to understand why multiple pointermove events occur before the first scroll event

In addition to the common fixes I've listed, what are some other steps to debug this type of issue?

Do you notice a significant drop in FPS when scrolling? There is a Chrome dev tool (native) that allow you to monitor that, it's called FPS meter. https://i.sstatic.net/8MWYlx7T.png

This might give you some hints, check the Scrolling performance issues on Chrome's rendering tab

It's very possible you have a javascript plugin that's messing with the scroll. For example, the plugin pagePiling hijacks the scroll event (Via return false in the event listener ) in order to provide a different experience. You can search your code for things that are listening to the scroll event. (It's very unlikely it's related to a CSS property, unless you're doing a whole bunch of animations during this scroll.) (Or, possibly, you have some code that's hijacking the pointermove event that takes a long time to complete. Check him too. )
